# I am new with Redux, can anyone help me with this problem

Tags: redux

[And here is my package.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekPmI.png)

```
{
  "name": "ReduxPrj",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "cli": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "^0.64.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "redux": "^4.1.0",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.14.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.26.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `import something from 'redux'` where you probably should be doing `import { something } from 'redux'`

But given that you don't share any code it's difficult to say any more.